# Scheme Binary Search Tree Adding Elements

Tags: debugging, tree, scheme, racket

To begin, I wanted to write a function that:

**Takes in:**

- A list of natural numbers, `(list 2 6 1 23...)` that could have repeating elements called "lst"
- A random binary search tree called "bst"

**Outputs:**

- An updated binary tree that adds every number on the list to it

**Code**

```
(define (recurse-lst bst lst)
  (cond [(empty? roster) empty]
        [(empty? lst) empty]
        [else (recurse-lst (bst-add bst (first lst)) (rest lst))]))

; helper function
(define (bst-add bst sublst)
  (cond [(empty? bst) (make-node (first sublst) empty empty)]
        [(< (first sublst) (node-key bst))
         (make-node (node-key bst)
                    (bst-add (node-left bst) (first sublst))
                    (node-right bst))]
        [else
         (make-node (node-key bst) (node-left bst)
                    (bst-add (node-right bst) (first sublst)))]))
```

**Problem**

I'm currently trying to get this working for nested lists; for example (list (list 1) (list 2)...), with each sub-list only having one element in them. However, it seems that it does not work and (first sublst) in bst-add turns the sublst into a number, like (first 1).

I think I've had similar bugs in other pieces of code before, but I cannot recall when and what it was.

Comment: yes, it would. you have answered your own question.

Comment: Thanks! Good to know. I tested my program again and it runs fine.

Comment: great! you can post your own answer with the working code here, and later accept it, to signal that the issue is resolved. :)

Comment: @WillNess sorry but this happened again - I messed up on something. I was doing this for a nested list with only one element in the nested list. However, the program failed to work. I've updated the code in the question. I wanted to make a new question for this but I feel that they are too closely related.

Comment: I've answered. for future questions please make new post(s). :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

right now you have

```
(define (recurse-lst bst lst)
   (cond [(empty? roster)
       ....
```

"`lst`".

"`roster`".

you need *always* to include your error messages in the posts on SO.

next. you call `(bst-add bst (first lst))` so the second argument in that call is already a number. yet in the definition of `bst-add` you name second parameter as "`sublst`" and treat it as a list. no need to take `first` again. and in fact taking `first` of a number is an error.

Comment: Yes - I realized that taking first was a mistake. The stepper/debugger showed the problem. Thanks for the clarification!